# Storyboard: Third scene to First scene inside NavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have three scenes embedded inside a Navigation Controller.

Scene1: Takes input from user, validates it to be > 0 and enables a button which pushes into Scene 2 using push segue.

Scene2: Depends on the value (say 'n') in the first scene,user has to move few sliders 'n' times by using a 'next' UIButton. When counter reaches n, another UIButton 'submit' is enabled for the user to push into Scene 3 using push segue.

Scene3: Shows the values of scene 2. Has a button "Start over" which pushes into scene 1 using push segue.

However, now when I'm in scene 1, there is back button from which user can go back to scene 3. How to prevent this from happening?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of *pushing* the first controller the "Start over" button should *pop* to the first controller.

Comment: Yes, `popToRootViewController`, or if iOS 6+, unwind segue.

Comment: :D Can't believe it is that simple! I removed the push segue, and in the touchUpInside event, added this line

[self.navigationcontroller popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

and boom, it works!